# Написание и отправка сообщения

Tags: html

Как на своём сайте сделать, чтобы можно было сообщение писать и отправлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) API - одну из их кнопок для отправки сообщений на почту

```
<a href="http://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/email/offer?pco=tbx32nj-1.0&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fhashcode.ru&amp;pubid=xa-4f2191b11bd7802f" target="_blank" ><img src="http://cache.addthis.com/icons/v1/thumbs/32x32/email.png" border="0" alt="email" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

создавайте текстовое поле и кнопку "Отправить"